# A simple test runner

Tags: javascript, unit-testing

When writing an answer for questions here or on Stack Overflow, it is a good idea to write some basic unit tests to make sure that the rewritten code performs as expected. To make this easier, I created a tiny test runner with the following goals.

1. Short - This is meant to be included in snippets, so it can't take up too much space.
2. Readable - Readability should not be sacrificed to make it a bit shorter.
3. Simple change to support objects, supports primitive values by default.

Here's a basic example of the usage:

```js
const test = ({ func, tests, equal = (a, b) => a === b, format = t => t }) => {
  let [passed, failed] = [0, 0]
  for (const { args, expected } of tests) {
    const result = func(...args)
    if (equal(result, expected)) {
      passed++
    } else {
      failed++
      console.log(`Expected ${func.name}(...${JSON.stringify(args)}) to equal ${format(expected)} but got ${format(result)}`)
    }
  }
  console.log(`${func.name} - Passed: ${passed} Failed: ${failed}`)
}

let tests = [
  { args: [1], expected: 2 },
  { args: [3], expected: 4 },
  { args: [-1], expected: 0 },
]

function badAddOne(n) { return n + "1" }
function goodAddOne(n) { return n + 1 }

test({ func: badAddOne, tests })
test({ func: goodAddOne, tests })

// Testing with a custom equals function
function createDate(epoch) {
  return new Date(parseInt(epoch, 10) * 1000)
}

test({
  tests: [
    { args: [ 1509220283 ], expected: new Date(1509220283000) },
    { args: [ 0 ], expected: new Date(0) },
    // Show the custom format function
    { args: [ 0 ], expected: new Date(1) }
  ],
  equal: (a, b) => a.getTime() === b.getTime(),
  format: d => d.toISOString(),
  func: createDate
})
```

What I'm looking for in a review:

1. Can this function be improved to make usage simpler? Would the signature `test(func, tests, { equal, format } = {})` make more sense?
2. Am I missing something a test runner designed for Stack Snippets should have that this function doesn't?

Edit:

1. This code uses the [JavaScript Standard Style](https://standardjs.com/demo.html).
2. Support for non modern (read obsolete) browsers is not important. I don't know any developers who use IE as a browser of choice and thus this code only needs to run on recent Firefox / Chrome versions.

Comment: SO code is in my view "Released" code, and thus should not have any associated testing code, but that is of course up to the author of the snippet. Some points (1) No support for legacy browsers <= IE11. Babel is problematic (I don't use it on SO as it breaks code, why? I never bothered to find out) (2) Don't output final results (last line of test function) You only need to know about bad code. (3) Does not pass any of the code lint/hinters I use (maybe some semicolons would be nice) (4) DONT USE `JSON.stringify` You don't have a try catch around it and it will throw for cyclic data.

Comment: @Blindman67 that looks a bit like a review to me, I've edited to address some points. What would you recommend instead of `JSON.stringify` (Is it even needed? How often do you pass objects with cyclic references to a function). I am considering the final results critique. I added it as every testing framework I've ever used outputs that information and I found it useful to know that the code did run when everything passed. (Maybe I'm missing something here?)

Comment: I am not a big fan of unit testing, thus I did not write a review. Re test pass output; If the code does not run you should throw an error. Re JSON; named tests would be better than having to output arguments (Reasons... what if I pass a 10MP image data array, or use the pattern `myObj = {array : []}; myObj.array.push({owner : myObj , ...data};` which I do a lot)